# How to use IsNetworkAlive function (Win32API) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, winapi, watir

I need to use this function for Watir, but it always returns 1, even if I manually cut off the connection.

```
require 'Win32API'

IsNetworkAlive = Win32API.new('sensapi.dll','IsNetworkAlive', nil, 'i')
boolean = IsNetworkAlive.call()
```

Not sure if parameters are properly given though...

1st is a required dll and according to [Bill Gates' site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is sensapi.dll. 2nd is the name of the function I want to instantiate. IsNetWorkAlive, that is. 3rd is the type of the function's parameter. None, hence nil. 4th is the type of a return value. Um, it's Boolean, but Ruby does have it. It should be either 0 or 1, so I could use int, perhaps.

Comment: ruby will treat anything as a bool, so you could specify bool there.

Comment: I changed the 4th parameter to bool, but it always returns 0...